# How to catch accessibility focus changed?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

I want to catch the accessibility focus change.

I searched and tried `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` but didn't trigger after cursor changed. I want to add value to button and after cursor change remove this value.

My code is like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    flashButton.accessibilityLabel = "Change the flash status"
    flashButton.accessibilityTraits = [.button]
    flashButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "flashButton"
}

@IBAction func flashButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    var currentFlashStatus = "off"
    guard let device =  AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) else { return }
    guard device.hasTorch else { return }
    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        if device.torchMode == .on {
            device.torchMode = .off
            flashButton.image = UIImage(named: "flashOffIcon")
            currentFlashStatus = "off"
        } else {
            do {
                try device.setTorchModeOn(level: 1.0)
                flashButton.image = UIImage(named: "flashOnIcon")
                currentFlashStatus = "on"
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    flashButton.accessibilityLabel = "Turned \(currentFlashStatus) the flash"
}
```

First, it reads "change the flash status" and if i double tap it reads "Turned on the flash status" which is correct.

If i change the cursor and come back to the flash button, it should say change the flash status again. But it says "turned on the flash status"

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I searched and tried `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused` but didn't trigger after cursor changed.

If you want to use the `UIAccessibilityFocus` informal protocol methods, you MUST override them in your object directly and not in the view controller *(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55629830/3825084))*. Create a subclass of `UIButton` for instance:

```
import UIKit

class FlashButton: UIButton {}

extension FlashButton {

    override open func accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused() {
    // Actions to be done when the element did become focused.
    }
}
```

> If I change the cursor and come back to the flash button, it should say change the flash status again.

Whatever the number of times you select the flash button, the desired status should be always read out first before saying to change its value.

An example is provided in the code hereafter:

```
class FlashButton: UIButton {

    private var intStatus: Bool = false
    private var a11yLabelStatus: String = "off"

    var status: Bool {
        get { return intStatus }
        set(newValue) { intStatus = newValue }
    }
}

extension FlashButton {

    override open func accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused() {
    // Actions to be done when the element did become focused.
    }

    override open func accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus() {
    // Actions to be done when the element did lose focus.
    }

    //This native a11y function replaces your defined IBAction to change and read out the flash status.
    override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool {

        intStatus = (intStatus == true) ? false : true
        a11yLabelStatus = (intStatus == true) ? "on" : "off"

        UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement,
                             argument: "flash status is " + a11yLabelStatus)
        return true
    }

    override var accessibilityLabel: String? {
        get { return "the flash status is " + a11yLabelStatus }
        set { }
    }

    override var accessibilityHint: String? {
        get { return "double tap to change the value." }
        set { }
    }
}
```

> How can I achieve this?

Either you try the `UIAccessibilityFocus` informal protocol to catch the focus change or you just use the code snippet above in order to **change the status of your accessibility element**: you can combine both, it's up to you to adapt these concepts in your coding environment.  ;o)

If it isn't enough, take a look at [this site](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#focus-an-element) dedicated to a11y developers where code snippets and illustrations are available to find out another solution for your implementation.

Comment: Really thanks for your reply. But I think there is a bug if it is a UIBarButtonItem. If It is a subclass of UIButton it is working perfectly. But if it is a subclass of UIBarButtonItem, accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused doesn't trigger.